# set color of character covered by cursor in vim(no gvim)

Tags: vim

The color of cursor sometimes is the same with the color of character, so when this character covered by cursor, it's hard to see it clearly, I want set the color of the character covered by cursor same to background, how to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This mostly depends on your chosen colorscheme; you could try out others. Mostly, the cursor is just a reverse representation of the character under it. It can be tweaked via `:hi Cursor ...`, see `:help :hi` for details.

In GVIM, you can also influence the appearance via `:set guicursor=...`, e.g. change it from the block to a horizontal line or underline.

Answer (score 4):

Use this configuration command, choosing a right color (black in this case):

```
:hi Cursor guifg=black
```

Comment: This is the right way to configure this feature. It works fine on GVim (an isolated application). Maybe you have to setup the proper setting of your console application.

Comment: for this problem, is there any difference between vim and gvim? I'm using vim in debian, not gvim.